# How to removing irrelevant data in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having a large data(image:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TFX1LQhQ-xwYp47fllL8PWwbwbv3wsb6/view?usp=drivesdk).The shape of data is 10000x100 .I want to remove irrelevant data by the condition(-0.5 =<angle<= 0.8).
the angle is a list of Angle_0,Angle_1,Angle_2......Angle_20.

`ang = [f"Angle_{i}" for i in range(20)]`

I want to have rows which follows the condition(-0.5 =<angle<= 0.8) for angle and delete other rows.

How to do this in python and pandas?

for example Angle_0 has value 0.1926715(row number 24) i want that row of entire dataset then in Angle_1 have data such as 0.1926715,0.192497 and i need those row(row number 7,9,14,16,19,21,23,26,28,29) similary for all other angles

I am a beginner in python.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you provide an expected output? I didn't get if you want to remove rows or columns.

Comment: for example Angle_0 has value 0.1926715(row number 24) i want that row of entire dataset then in Angle_1 have data such as 0.1926715,0.192497 and i need those row(row number 7,9,14,16,19,21,23,26,28,29) similary for all other angles @SalvatoreDanieleBianco

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = df[(df['angle']>=-0.5 and df['angle']<=0.8]
```

Comment: the angle is a list of Angle_0,Angle_1 .......Angle_20.Can use your line for this?

Comment: @Mageo this won't work for you. You will need to provide a list like this ['Angle_0','Angle_1','Angle_2'..]. Or just check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the rows that contain at least one angle that does not follow your conditions, this will solve your problem:

```
df.loc[(df>=-0.5 & df<=0.8).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: but this will check the entire dataset,right? My dataset has many other columns other than angles

Comment: yes it does. If one angle does not fit your rules, this command will remove all the row.

Comment: I dont want to check my entire dataset but only on angles and filter the entire dataset based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty way:

```
for n in range (20):
  column_name = "Angle_" + str(n)
  df = df[(df[column_name]>=-0.5 & df[column_name]<=0.8]
```

Since you need to adress several columns starting with the name Angle you could use regex like this to select them:

```
df = df.loc[(df.filter(regex='^Angle_') >=-0.5).all(axis=1) & (df.filter(regex='^Angle_')<=0.8).all(axis=1)]
```

The second solution is better in case you get a variable amount of angles or if it might change later

Comment: i tried with the second one and gives me error:*ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Mageo sry it should be "&" instead of "and"

Comment: @Mageo also slightly changed

Comment: @Mageo let me know if it worked